# Spring Integration issue on RabbitMQ cluster restart

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

We have several RabbitMQ queues in our system and we use Spring Integration amqp:inbound-channel-adapter to consume the messages. The Spring application runs on 5 JBoss nodes (not in cluster)

RabbitMQ side is a two clustered nodes with a load balancer, with durable queues, on the application side listeners definition is quite simple with a connection factory defined as follows:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactory" username="${orts.rabbitmq.username}" password="${orts.rabbitmq.password}"
host="${orts.rabbitmq.endpoint}" />
```

and several inbound-channel-adapter defined like the following:

```
<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="artiqAmqpInboundChannelAdapter"
  channel="artiq.queued.action.filter.outbound.channel" error-channel="artiq.recovery.router.channel"
connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" header-mapper="amqpHeaderMapper"
  queue-names="ortsArtiqQueue" />
```

We had experienced an unexpected behavior when for some reason (i.e. deploying a new configuration) we have to restart the RabbitMQ cluster, after restart it happens that one or more of the listeners stop consuming messages and we have to restart JBoss nodes to recover.

Note that this behavior is not bound to a specific queue, each time the impacted queues may be different.
Also note that the new configuration deployed doesn't modify any of the existing queues (it happened for example when we added new queues)

Answer (score 0):

> the listeners stop consuming messages and we have to restart JBoss nodes to recover.

In my experience such problems are invariably because the listener container thread is "stuck" in some code downstream of the adapter.

To debug, next time it happens take a thread dump (e.g. with `jstack`) and look at what the consumer threads are doing.

It doesn't sound like this is your problem, but we did recently [fix a bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-621) which caused a similar problem when adding/removing queues to/from an existing listener container. If you are not doing that, then that fix won't help you; you need to look at the thread dump to see what's happening.

Comment: Hi @Gary, thanks for the quick reply, we are working on setting up the same infrastructure on our staging environment (i.e. a rabbit cluster instead of a single node) to reproduce the problem, it will take some time, so I will get back with further information as soon as we reproduced it

Comment: I doubt that rabbitmq being in a cluster is the issue; more likely it's due to higher volume in production - perhaps some thread-safety issue in downstream components causing the thread to get hung up.

Comment: it's really possible, I just want to work on an environment as close as possible to the production one to include all factors, it won't take too long and so far it seems that we have problems only when "touching" RabbitMQ, and we don't do it too frequently

Comment: Hi @Gary, as we are experiencing similar problems with RabbitMQ also from a PHP client we moved our investigation more on RabbitMQ side and we are reviewing our infrastructure set up, I'll be back with some news ASAP

Comment: Hi @Gary, I've been able to reproduce the issue on our staging environment. I made a small change to RabbitMQ connection factory configuration to use addresses instead of host with the two IPs of the RabbitMQ nodes, and collected the dumps before and after stopping and starting RabbitMQ nodes, as well as netstat output from the JBoss server at every RabbitMQ start/stop, how can I share them? (it's quite an amount of data)

Comment: There are several places you can put such things; pastebin, a github gist, dropbox, etc, etc.

Comment: Hi @Gary, I uploaded the dump files and the netstat output on droppbox, the link is https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cxotk92x0bk0l4o/AABZWT-VhmctU4psqs-8QmfFa?dl=0 let me know if you have problems to access it

Comment: I don't see any Spring code in any of your dumps so it doesn't appear to be an application (or Spring) problem with hanging threads. So it's some kind of connectivity issue; I can't help with that. You might want to try the rabbit guys on the rabbitmq-users google group.

Comment: Hi @Gary, I had the same feeling, thank you for your help